# If an operation on a float is atomic in .NET then why do I get different values here?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, atomic

I have some code which is its simplest form does the following.

```
float result = RunSimulation();
totalResult += result;
```

If I run this in a single thread I get different results compared to running it in multiple threads. If I put a lock around the totalResult addition then I get the same result but at a massive performance cost.

With floats being 32 bit I thought that operations on them were guaranteed to be atomic, so I don't understand why threading this is giving me different results.

I can just use ThreadStatic fields to keep count of to totals and then add them together with locks when the threads terminate, so it's not a solution that I'm looking for, just an explanation.

I wrote some test code to check this in it's simplest form. This code is as follows and also produces different results for every run.

```
class Program
{
    static float total;
    static int threadCount;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                new Thread(ThreadMethod).Start();

            do
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            } while (threadCount > 0);

            Console.WriteLine(total);
            if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                break;
        }
    }

    static void ThreadMethod()
    {
        threadCount++;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            total = total + 1.234f;

        threadCount--;
    }
}
```

Comment: `x += y` is not an atomic operation, it is the same as `x = x + y` so involves two reads and a write.

Comment: Reading *or* writing a `float` is atomic. Reading *and then* writing it is not atomic as a whole.

Comment: Atomicity only guarantees that you'll never read a partially written value.  Where some bytes are updated and some bytes still have the old value.  That's a pretty weak guarantee and a thousand miles removed from having to ensure that read-modify-write operations like you are using occur in an un-interruptable order with a non-stale view of the memory content.  Using the *lock* keyword is required here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading and writing floats is atomic, this is [guaranteed by the language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691278%28VS.71%29.aspx). However, operations on floats are not atomic. There is no way around using some kind of syncing in this case.

On a sidenote, you have a small race condition, the while might exit before any thread was ever started.

Comment: @WillCalderwood I think it's more of an OS problem rather than CPU (not sure), but yeah, not important here anyway :)